# Understanding bounded linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, transformation

The definition of a bounded linear operator is a linear transformation $T$ between two normed vectors spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that the ratio of the norm of $T(v)$ to that of $v$ is bounded by the same number, over all non-zero vectors in $X$.

What is this definition saying, is it saying that the norm of vectors is preserved under the transformation?

Why does ratio come into it?, the ratio of what?

Comment: That a linear operator is bounded means simply that it is Lipschitz. It turns out to be equivalent to continuity in case of normed spaces.

Comment: Details are covered in other posts. For context, the interest arises because a bounded linear operator is continuous. It's easy to show that a linear operator on a finite dimensional space is bounded (and therefore continuous). Things become more interesting in infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: It might also be instructive to see what a not-bounded operator looks like. For example, the derivative operator $C^1(\mathbb{R}) \to C(\mathbb{R})$, where $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is equipped with the $\sup$ norm inherited from $C(\mathbb{R})$. You can make the operator bounded by equipping $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $u \mapsto \| u \|_\infty + \| u' \|_\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_r(x)$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$:
$$
              B_{r}(x) = \{ y : \|x-y\| < r \}.
$$
A linear transformation $T$ is continuous at $x$ iff, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
               T(B_{\delta}(x)) \subseteq B_{\epsilon}(Tx)
$$
Because of linearity, the above is equivalent to
$$
                      T(B_{\delta}(0))\subseteq B_{\epsilon}(0).
$$
So $T$ is continuous at $0$ iff it is continuous at every $x$. Furthermore, because of how linear transformations commute with scalar multiplication, continuity at $0$ is equivalent to the existence of $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
                   T(B_{\delta}(0)) \subseteq B_{1}(0).
$$
Indeed the above holds for some $\delta > 0$ iff
$$
               T(B_{\delta\epsilon}(0))\subseteq B_{\epsilon}(0).
$$
Another equivalent is that $T(B_{1}(0))$ is contained in some finite ball $B_{r}(0)$. That is, $T$ is continuous at every $x$ iff there exists $r > 0$ such that
$$
                T(B_{1}(0)) \subseteq B_{r}(0).
$$
Equivalently, there exists $r > 0$ such that
$$
                  \|Tx\|_{Y} \le r\|x\|_{X},\;\;\; x\in X.
$$
This last condition is the definition of a bounded transformation.

Answer (score 1):

What the definition is saying is that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that, for every $v\in X$:
$$\|T(v)\|\le C\|v\|.$$
In other words, the ratio $\frac{\|T(v)\|}{\|v\|}$ is bounded by the same constant $C$, regardless $v\in X$. Note that the latter requires $v\ne 0$ for the ratio to be defined.

Comment: It seems that the OP know this already.

Comment: @AugSB where $v$ is any vector in $x$ right?

Comment: Of course, it can be any $v\in X$. Additionally, if you use the ratio definition, $v\ne 0$.

Comment: See the answers below. Example: For  $X=Y=R^2$ each with the norm $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt {x^2+y^2},$ and $T(x,y)=(2 x,3 y)$ we have $ \|T\|=3.$